# run `nmake` while the current directoy in debug folder

Tags: c++, windows-7, nmake

I would like to know if is it possible to run `nmake` from command prompt while the current directory is in debug folder. I found it tedious to change to the previous folder only to run `nmake` then come back to debug folder to run the executable file.

```
debug
release
main.cpp
Makefile
```

I'm using visual studio 2010 in windows 7.

Comment: I recommend you read an [`nmake` reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd9y37ha%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, under which section exactly? I'm not sure if `nmake` has something to do with my problem.

Answer (score 1):

By using [nmake option /F](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/afyyse50(v=vs.100).aspx) you can specify the location of your Makefile:

```
nmake /F ..\Makefile
```

Alternatively you can invoke a sequence of commands in a single line:

```
pushd .. & nmake & popd
```